# Creating new file with touch command in PowerShell error message

Tags: git, powershell

I have a directory on my desktop created using PowerShell, and now I'm trying to create a text file within it.

I did change directory to the new one, and typed `touch textfile.txt`.

This is the error message I get:

```
touch : The term 'touch' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, 
script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was 
included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

At line:1 char:1
+ touch file.txt
+ ~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (touch:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException`
```

Why is it not working? Will I have to use Git Bash all the time?

Comment: If you want to use msys/etc. commands then you need to use git bash or have configured git bash to "pollute" your system `%PATH%` with its bin directories. `touch` isn't a Windows or powershell command. You can't use `Write-Error`, etc. from git bash either.

Comment: thanks you for your answer!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If you need a command `touch` in PowerShell you could define a function that does The Right Thing™:

```
function touch {
  Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$Path
  )

  if (Test-Path -LiteralPath $Path) {
    (Get-Item -Path $Path).LastWriteTime = Get-Date
  } else {
    New-Item -Type File -Path $Path
  }
}
```

Put the function in your [profile](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/05/21/understanding-the-six-powershell-profiles.aspx) so that it's available whenever you launch PowerShell.

Defining `touch` as an alias (`New-Alias -Name touch -Value New-Item`) won't work here, because `New-Item` has a mandatory parameter `-Type` and you can't include parameters in PowerShell alias definitions.

Comment: Is there a race condition if multiple processes do this simultaneously? The Really Right Thing for `touch` is to *atomically* create the file if it doesn't exist.

Comment: Well, the code in my answer obviously is not atomic. That would probably require something like trying to create the item, and catching/handling errors at the very least.

Answer (score 29):

If you're using Windows Powershell, the equivalent command to Mac/Unix's touch is: `New-Item textfile.txt -type file`.

Comment: This is not strictly true. `touch` will update a file's timestamp if it exists, without affecting its content. `New-Item` will fail if the file exists.

Answer (score 29):

For single file creation in power shell :
`ni textfile.txt`

For multiple files creation at a same time:
`touch a.txt,b.html,x.js` is the linux command
`ni a.txt,b.html,x.js` is the windows power shell command

Comment: While I understand based on some other answers that this is not exactly the same as touch, this is exactly what I needed for my common use case.

Answer (score 11):

As [Etan Reisner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/258523/etan-reisner) pointed out, `touch` is not a command in Windows nor in PowerShell.

If you want to just create a new file quickly (it looks like you're not interested in the use case where you just update the date of an existing file), you can use these:

```
$null > textfile.txt
$null | sc textfile.txt
```

Note that the first one will default to Unicode, so your file won't be empty; it will contain 2 bytes, the [Unicode BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).

The second one uses `sc` (an alias for `Set-Content`), which [defaults to the system's active ANSI code page when used on the FileSystem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content?view=powershell-5.1), which uses no BOM and therefore truly creates an empty file.

If you use an empty string (`''` or `""` or `[String]::Empty`) instead of `$null` you'll end up with a line break also.

Comment: I'm at the prompt `$C:\Users\...\folder> ` If I type `textfile.txt` I get an error message. So far it only works if I type `notepad textfile.txt` and after being prompted by an error message that indicates that there is no such file, I click on the option of creating it.

Comment: If you don't want the Unicode BOM, just use `Add-Content textfile.txt $null`

Comment: My pleasure, Brian. If you ever feel inspired, you could update the answer with the PowerShell Core perspective (consistent use of BOM-less UTF-8, `sc` no longer being a built-in alias for `Set-Content`).

Comment: @mklement0 I don't think I'll be able to anytime soon, but you could post a new answer, or edit into your exiting one, and I'd be happy too upvote it and link to it directly from this answer; or you may of course edit this further (though I'd prefer you get the vote credits!).

Answer (score 6):

if you are using node, just use this command and it will install touch.

**`npm install touch-cli -g`**

Comment: This is a good solution!

Answer (score 5):

Here's the `touch` method with better error handling:

```
function touch
{
    $file = $args[0]
    if($file -eq $null) {
        throw "No filename supplied"
    }

    if(Test-Path $file)
    {
        throw "file already exists"
    }
    else
    {
        # echo $null > $file
        New-Item -ItemType File -Name ($file)
    }
}
```

Add this function to `C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1` (create this file if doesn't exist).

Use it like this: `touch hey.js`

Comment: This is the most accurate solution IMO.

Answer (score 2):

cd into the your path where you want the file to be created and then type...

New-item -itemtype file yourfilenamehere.filetype

*example*

New-item -itemtype file index.js

Answer (score 2):

To generalize [Ansgar Wiechers' helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32451953/45375), in order to support:

- *multiple* files as input, passed as *individual* arguments (`touch file1 file2`, as with the Unix `touch` utility) rather than as an *array* argument (`touch file1, file2`), the latter being the PowerShell-idiomatic way to pass multiple values to a *single* parameter.
- *wildcard* patterns as input (only meaningful when targeting *existing files*, to update their last-write timestamps).
- `-Verbose` to get feedback on what actions are performed.

Note:

- The function only emulates the *core* functionality of the Unix `touch` utility:

  - for *existing* files, it sets the last-write and last-access timestamps to the current point in time,
  - whereas *non-existing* files are created, with no content.
- For a more complete emulation that is also more PowerShell-idiomatic, `Touch-File`, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58756360/45375).
- The function requires PowerShell version 4 or higher, due to use of the `.ForEach()` array method (though it could easily be adapted to earlier versions).

```sh
function touch {
<#
.SYNOPSIS
Emulates the Unix touch utility's core functionality.
#>
  param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromRemainingArguments)]
    [string[]] $Path
  )

  # For all paths of / resolving to existing files, update the last-write timestamp to now.
  if ($existingFiles = (Get-ChildItem -File $Path -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorVariable errs)) {
    Write-Verbose "Updating last-write and last-access timestamps to now: $existingFiles"
    $now = Get-Date
    $existingFiles.ForEach('LastWriteTime', $now)
    $existingFiles.ForEach('LastAccessTime', $now)
  }

  # For all non-existing paths, create empty files.
  if ($nonExistingPaths = $errs.TargetObject) {
    Write-Verbose "Creatng empty file(s): $nonExistingPaths"
    $null = New-Item $nonExistingPaths
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The combination of `New-Item` with the `Name`, `ItemType`, and `Path` parameters worked for me. In my case, to create a `_netrc` file for git:

```
 New-Item -Name _netrc -ItemType File -Path $env:userprofile
```

**References**

- [Permanently authenticating with Git repositories - Atlassian Documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/permanently-authenticating-with-git-repositories-776639846.html)
- [Powershell - Windows Environment variables - PowerShell - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-env.html)
- [New-Item - PowerShell - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/ps/new-item.html)

Answer (score 1):

How about just use this to create .txt file in PowerShell.

`New-Item .txt`

Check this [website](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/powershell/powershell_filesio_create_text.htm) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

I like to extend the function to create a non-existing folder by default.  If you want the traditional behavior providing the option is nice.

```
function touch {
  param([string]$Name,
    [switch]$Traditional)
  if (-not $Traditional) {
    $names = $Name.Replace("\", "/").Replace("//", "/") -split "/"
    $nameNormalized = $names -join "/"
    $nameNormalized = $nameNormalized.TrimEnd($names[$names.count - 1]).TrimEnd("/")
    if (-not (Test-Path $nameNormalized) -and ($names.count -gt 1)) {      
      New-Item -Path $nameNormalized -ItemType Directory > $null
    }    
  }
  if (-not (Test-Path $Name)) {
    New-Item -Path $Name -ItemType File >$null
  }
  else {
  (Get-Item -Path $Name).LastWriteTime = Get-Date
  }
}
```

usage:

```
# will make the folder if it doesn't exist
touch filepath\file.extension
# will throw exception if the folder doesn't exist
touch filepath\file.extension -Traditional
# both will make the file or update the LastWriteTime if the file already exists
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Window's Power Shell, then the touch command may show an error.
Use:

```
New-Item* filename.filetype
```

or

```
ni* filename.filetype
```

For example:

```
New-Item name.txt or ni name.txt
```

Comment: I believe this answer has already been suggested...

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I`m just create a alias do command` ni`in my`user_profile.ps1` file.

```
Set-Alias touch ni
```

Then I can use this command to create files, for example: `touch example.js anotherone.md another.tsx`

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your Windows pwsh profile and reload

function touch ($myNewFileName)
{
New-Item $myNewFileName -type file
}

touch seems to work in pwsh OOB in MacOS