# How to create an empty log or text file with Powershell using date or timestamp?

Tags: powershell, file, timestamp, pipe, system-administration

How to create an empty file with powershell, similar to "touch" on Linux, with a timestamp in the filename?

not too different from:

```
md5sum /etc/mtab > "$(date +"%Y_%m_%d_%I_%M_%p").log"
```

although that file isn't actually empty, but it does have the date incorporated into the filename itself.

Attempts on Powershell:

```
PS /home/nicholas/powershell/file_ops> New-Item -ItemType file  foo.txt

New-Item: The file '/home/nicholas/powershell/file_ops/foo.txt' already exists.

New-Item: The file '/home/nicholas/powershell/file_ops/foo.txt' already exists.
PS /home/nicholas/powershell/file_ops> New-Item -ItemType file  bar.txt

    Directory: /home/nicholas/powershell/file_ops

Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-----          12/20/2020 10:56 AM              0 bar.txt

PS /home/nicholas/powershell/file_ops> $logfile = "./"+$FN+"-LOG-AddUser_$(get-date -Format yyyymmdd_hhmmtt).txt"
```

ideally, to generate an arbitrary number of empty log or text files.

see also:

https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1194231-powershell-adding-a-variable-into-a-log-filename

https://superuser.com/q/502374/977796

https://4sysops.com/archives/understanding-the-powershell-_-and-psitem-pipeline-variables/

https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/278939/101935

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the simplest case, **if you want to *unconditionally create* a file, use `New-Item -Force`** - but note that if the target file exists, its content is *discarded*:

```
# CAVEAT: Truncates an existing file. `-ItemType File` is implied.
#  * Outputs a [System.IO.FileInfo] instance describing the new file, which
# $null = ... discards here.
#  * `Get-Date -UFormat` allows you to perform Unix-style date formatting.
$null = New-Item -Force "$(Get-Date -UFormat "%Y_%m_%d_%I_%M_%p").log"
```

- [`New-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-item)'s (positionally implied) `-Path` parameter supports an *array* of paths, so you can pass multiple paths at once.
- By default, an *empty* file is created, but you may optionally provide (initial) *content* via the `-Value` parameter.

---

**More work is needed if you truly want to emulate the `touch` Unix utility's behavior**, which *by default* means (note that [`touch`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/touch.html) supports a variety of options<sup>[1]</sup>):

- If a file doesn't exist yet, *create it* (as an empty file).
- Otherwise, *update the last-modified timestamp* to the current point in time (and leave the existing content alone).

```
$file = "$(Get-Date -UFormat "%Y_%m_%d_%I_%M_%p").log"
# Trick: This dummy operation leaves an existing file alone,
#        but creates the file if it doesn't exist.
Add-Content -LiteralPath $file -Value $null
(Get-Item -LiteralPath $file).LastWriteTime = Get-Date
```

Note:

- The above is limited to a single file specified by literal path, and doesn't include error handling.
- See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58756360/45375) for **custom PowerShell function `Touch-File`**, which implements most of the `touch` utility's functionality in PowerShell-idiomatic fashion, including the ability to handle *wildcard* patterns correctly.

  - Said function is **also available as [an MIT-licensed Gist](https://gist.github.com/mklement0/82ed8e73bb1d17c5ff7b57d958db2872)**. Assuming you have looked at the linked code to ensure that it is safe (which I can personally assure you of, but you should always check), you can install it directly as follows:

    ```
    irm https://gist.github.com/mklement0/82ed8e73bb1d17c5ff7b57d958db2872/raw/Touch-File.ps1 | iex
    ```

---

<sup>[1] The linked page is `touch`'s POSIX spec, which mandates *minimum* functionality; concrete implementations may support more.</sup>