# PowerShell script to name file using user input

Tags: powershell, input

Using PowerShell. Trying to label a filename using a variable that the user enters.

```
function foo
{ $name = Read-Host -Prompt "Get name"
...
....
}

foo | Out-file -FilePath c:\temp\$name.log
```

result is a file is made but its just `c:\temp\.log`. How can I use input to the `$name` to name the file?

Comment: The file should always go to `C:\temp` ? What happens if the file with the same name already exists in the destination ?

Comment: I guess your answer is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32448174/creating-new-file-with-touch-command-in-powershell-error-message or pretty close to it

Comment: any directory,  i label the file as a different week by input.

Answer (score 1):

- Creating a variable *inside a function* creates a *local* variable and therefore doesn't make it visible to the *caller*.

  - There are ways to create a variable in the *parent* scope, but such techniques are best avoided in the interest of encapsulation.
- Thus, if you want the caller to act on the *value* of `$name`, *output* its value from the function, or output the user response *directly*, as shown below.

```
# Define a function that prompts the user for a name
# *and outputs it* - no strict need for a variable.
function foo { Read-Host -Prompt "Get name" }

# Now use an expandable string ("...") with a subexpression ($(...))
# to call the function and embed its output in the string.
# Note that this either creates a new empty file or
# truncates an existing file.
Out-File -FilePath "c:\temp\$(foo).log"
```